# Run a command line command from a file

Tags: node.js

Is there was a way to log all console statements to a file in node.

I was recently working on a mini project and wanted to find out how to run cli commands and save it's output to a file.

For ex:
`node -v` would output `v9.7.1` on the terminal. How do i execute it from a file and note down it's output? I tried putting the same command in a JS file and running `node test.js` but it returned the following error.

```
/home/kashyap/Documents/Code/testgits/1.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { node -v
                                                              ^
ReferenceError: node is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/kashyap/Documents/Code/testgits/1.js:1:63)
    at Module._compile (module.js:662:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:673:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:575:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:515:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:507:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:703:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:193:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:660:3
```

How do i run console commands in a file. Similar to writing a script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `child_process` module

```
const spawn = require('child_process');

spawn.exec('node -v', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (err) {
        return;
    }
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
});
```

> stdout: v8.9.4